# Erro no JS referente ao PieChart NVD3, não consigo identificar o problema

Tags: javascript, jquery

Após atualizar a versão do `nv.d3.min.js` para versão `1.8.6`, quando passo o mouse sobre o chart apresenta incontáveis erros no retorno da função, e o `tooltip` parou de funcionar também, li vários manuais e materiais inclusive github, e não encontrei uma solução.

Continuando as pesquisas descobri que por algum motivo no parâmetro this.namespaceURI está sendo passado como indefinido. Porem ainda sem solução.

Descobri que o problema é exatamente na criação do tooltip, os erros foram interrompidos com a inserção da linha

> chart.tooltip.enabled(false);
>   porem eu preciso usar o tooltip e não sei como resolver.

```
d3_selectionPrototype.append = function(name) {
name = d3.ns.qualify(name);
function append() {
  return this.appendChild(d3_document.createElementNS(this.namespaceURI, name));
}
```

segue um exemplo do erro ocorrido.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.appendChild is not a function
at append (http://localhost:52720/Content/js/plugins/nvd3/lib/d3.v3.js?20170731121208:794:19)
at Array.d3_selection_enterPrototype.select (http://localhost:52720/Content/js/plugins/nvd3/lib/d3.v3.js?20170731121208:1070:57)
at Array.d3_selectionPrototype.append (http://localhost:52720/Content/js/plugins/nvd3/lib/d3.v3.js?20170731121208:799:17)
at b (http://localhost:52720/Content/js/plugins/nvd3/nv.d3.min.js?20170731121208:14:5774)
at http://localhost:52720/Content/js/plugins/nvd3/nv.d3.min.js?20170731121208:14:6054
at Object.a.dom.write (http://localhost:52720/Content/js/plugins/nvd3/nv.d3.min.js?20170731121208:14:2071)
at c (http://localhost:52720/Content/js/plugins/nvd3/nv.d3.min.js?20170731121208:14:6037)
at Object.set (http://localhost:52720/Content/js/plugins/nvd3/nv.d3.min.js?20170731121208:14:10400)
at Function.a._calls.a._calls.(anonymous function).a.(anonymous function) [as hidden] (http://localhost:52720/Content/js/plugins/nvd3/nv.d3.min.js?20170731121208:14:15684)
at d3_dispatch.<anonymous> (http://localhost:52720/Content/js/plugins/nvd3/nv.d3.min.js?20170731121208:20:4287)
```

******Problema resolvido.******

Precisei fazer atualização do arquivo d3v3.js no diretório NVD3>LIB,
peguei o código no dominio: https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js